# android home screen widget onReceive() call for custom intent

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, appwidgetprovider

I am trying to create a home screen widget with 3 buttons. To test code, onReceive() I am calling same activities for time being.
I am following below tutorials.

http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/modal-popup-from-android-widget-example

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/modal-dialog-popup-from-android-widget-example.html

which are well explained for home screen widget for one Button. However, when I click on any button, onReceive() is not getting called. But onReceive() is called when adding widget to home screen or removing from but not button click.

I need to call different activity for different button. But onReceive() itself not getting called. Unable to figure where I am doing wrong even in debugging.

Nothing is happening when I click on any button on home screen widget.

Below is android manifest file

```
            <receiver
        android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_1" />
            <action android:name="com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_2" />
            <action android:name="com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_3" />
        </intent-filter> <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/tagit_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Below is MyWidgetProvider code:

```
    public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
private static final String ACTION_HANDLE_1 = "com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_1";
private static final String ACTION_HANDLE_2 = "com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_2";
private static final String ACTION_HANDLE_3 = "com.test.testapp1.action.HANDLE_1";

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for(int i = 0; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++) {
        int appid = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_HANDLE_1);
        //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchActivity, 0);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text1, pendingIntent);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_HANDLE_2);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text2, pendingIntent);

        intent.setAction(ACTION_HANDLE_3);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_text3, pendingIntent);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appid, views);
    }

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_HANDLE_1)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HelpActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);

    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_HANDLE_2)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HelpActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);

    } else if(intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_HANDLE_3)) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HelpActivity.class);
        intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent1);

    }
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

}

No errors shown in logcat.

2nd issue is on android 5.0, widget is showing (both physical phone and emulator) but android 4.3 emulator, widget is not showing widget's selection.

unable to figure out where I am doing wrong.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. There are 2 issues in my code. Intent should be created by passing AppWidgetProvider class name i.e MyWidgetProvider.class as second argument to new Intent(). 2nd is if widget is having more than 1 button, for each need to do 

        intent = new Intent(context, MyWdgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_HANDLE_1);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

And  update remote view with views.setOnClickPendingIntent() - This is once. 
Checked that onReceve() getting called now.

Comment: Your solution has been so helpful to me

Comment: There is no need in adding your actions into <intent-filter>. The key problem is that you need to use PendingIntent.getBroadcast to deliver the Intent to your MyWidgetProvider.class